# MySQL – Generating Row Number for Each Row Using Variable

Tags: mysql

Oracle query is-

```
select ROW_NUMBER () OVER(order by shortunitdesc) as SLNO, 
om.shortunitdesc,oc.operparam as Parameter, 
oc.tagno,oc.severity,lowlimit,highlimit, oc.operrange, IMPLICATION, DURATION from  oeconfig oc, oeunitmaster om 
where oc.unitcode = om.unitcode;
```

I want to convert in mysql, so I have tried

```
select @i:=@i+1 as slno, om.shortunitdesc, oc.operparam as Parameter, 
oc.tagno,oc.severity,oc.lowlimit,oc.highlimit,oc.operrange , IMPLICATION, DURATION 
from oeconfig oc oeunitmaster om , (select @i := 0) 
where oc.unitcode = om.unitcode 
order by shortunitdesc;
```

but it gives an error-  Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select @i:=@i+1 as slno, om.shortunitdesc, oc.operparam as Parameter, 
oc.tagno,oc.severity,oc.lowlimit,oc.highlimit,oc.operrange , IMPLICATION, DURATION 
from oeconfig oc, oeunitmaster om, (select @i := 0) t
where oc.unitcode = om.unitcode 
order by shortunitdesc;
```